Why does my light switch in attic flicker inconsistently?
I moved in to new apartment and noticed that the light switch in attic flickers when it is off. I read that it is common in order to find the switch in the dark, but it flickers inconsistently. In this video you can see that it flickers, then stops, then starts again, and so on. Other times (not shown in the video) it flickers literally once and then the light around the switch turns off completely. Should it flicker at all? If yes, is this normal to flicker inconsistently?
UPDATE
Forgot to mention, the switch controls the light bulb on the opposite wall from the switch. If I unscrew the light bulb, this "indicator neon lamp" around the switch does not even light up. Does it need a light bulb to turn on the neon, since the light bulb closes the circuit?

Would think the light is old and wearing out.  Being in an apartment you are probably allowed to change a switch, but CYA and having the landlord have an electrician in, is good insurance for yourself.

that's normal for neon bulbs ... shine a light on it and it should light up solidly ... the extra light gives it more energy to light

@jsotola, sorry, just to be sure, by "bulb" you refer to this thin "envelop" around the switch, right?

When they get old these neon indicator lamps become intermittent because the radioactive krypron-85 decays.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neon_lamp
So it's the expected aging performance of the indicator lamp, and  it's probably not indicative on an electrical fault.
Look for other evidence of an electrical fault, if you don't see, hear, or smell any. it's safe to ignore the flickering.

How do I verify that the issue is indeed with the indicator lamp? Do I replace the whole switch or can I just replace the indicator lamp? Also, please see my update in my post with the question regarding how the bulb affects this neon indicator.

@theateist the light bulb provides a path to neutral for the neon indicator lamp. If it's open circuit the neon won't light, and CFL or LED bulbs also won't (usually) work for the neon. The flickering is a different issue

Understood. Back to my first question, how do I verify the the flickering is due to decay or something in the circuit, do I need to replace the whole switch for that or is there any easier way?

@theateist The neon indicator lamp is buried deep in the switch handle and isn't normally accessible. Even if it's a loose connection, you'd probably have to completely disassemble the switch to check it, and switches aren't usually made disassemble-able. Your best bet is to have the switch replaced with a new lit wall switch.

How do I verify that the issue is indeed with the indicator lamp? Why do you want to do that?  The flickering does not indicate a problem.  If it's not causing a problem ignore it. If there's some other evidence of a problem address that. How is you hire an electrician to replace the switch and then disasseble the old swtich and using a 200V laboratory power supply measure the strike voltage of the indicator.

To answer the newest part of the question:

If I unscrew the light bulb, this "indicator neon lamp" around the switch does not even light up. Does it need a light bulb to turn on the neon, since the light bulb closes the circuit?

This is totally normal. Any light, including a light on a switch, needs to get power from somewhere. A light switch will always (well, except the one I just replaced that was switching neutral, which is against code...) have a "hot" wire but it needs to take the power from "hot" and complete a circuit somehow.
There are a few ways to do that:

Battery - Doesn't use the "hot" wire. Works great, but requires periodic replacement.
Neutral - Many older homes don't have neutral in a lot of switch boxes.
Ground - Allowed only in very limited low-power situations.
Leak current through the regular load

That last one is what a typical neon-light switch does, and you have confirmed that it works that way. This works very well with incandescent lights. It often does not work well with modern LED lights because they can visibly glow with only a little bit of current. Or even worse: flash annoyingly.
